# Issue with meta tags in iPhone simulator

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive-design, meta-tags

I'm using meta tags to scale a site.

It's for a demo on an iphone, so **best practices can be ignored**.

For some reason the scaling does not seem to change when I change the page from landscape to portrait. (I'm not talking about switching while rotating, I'm talking about full page reloads in a different orientation).

I'm testing the site in the iPhone simulator.

Am I missing something simple?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320; initial-scale=.675">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480; initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using two viewport tags? These are not if-then statements; you should set the viewport value once. As it stands I would expect the second one to override the first (though really, anything can happen).

Also don't confuse width with device-width. Might help to reread http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: thanks, will go back to media queries on my css. I thought a quick fix might be available with two meta tags. Appreciate the link.